# XYZ Data, Spike Detection

Tags: windows, gis

I have tons of LiDAR Bathymetric XYZ data with 5m resolution.

The data has a lot of noise/spikes which takes ages to clean for a small area. I have tried using Fledermaus for 3D cleaning the data. Is there any software available to automatically clean and visualize the data, using Standard Deviation?
I am using Windows 7 OS, 64bit.

Comment: On what OS/platform should it run, and how much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid software?

Comment: hi, Iam using Windows 7. Do u already have any tools developed ? Iam not sure if i will able to pay.. If it doesnt cost a lot I might think about.

Comment: Welcome Santosh! Would you mind updating your question and tags with the information your provided in response to Izzy's questions?

Comment: What @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket meant is: you can always edit your own posts using the **[edit]** link directly below your post's body (actually, once you gained some rep, you can even edit other people's posts to improve quality). // As to your other question: no, I'm not a developer. I'm just another member of this community, and one of my goals here is helping new members improving their chance for good matching answers, finding there way on this site, etc.  So your adding "Windows & not too expensive" already on that path :)